# Unable to add new version in app store in app store connect

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I have a live version for my app on app store which i 0.0.151.
Now i am unable to add new version because i can't see the (+) add button option only in my appstore connect.

Looking forward for response.

[image: attached screenshot]

Comment: Is there any version other than **Ready for Sale**? If so, you can not add another one.  You can share screenshot for that.

Comment: No. Only READY for sale version is available. I have edited the post please check the link for screenshot.

Comment: In a normal way there is one "Ready for Sale" version, that means the version is available in AppStore. There are two for your case. btw you can [report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) it.

Comment: Normally, apps *do not* have two versions marked `Ready for Sale`. (Maybe it's possible if you are targeting different iOS versions, but your question doesn't say this.) Unless you can give us more details, maybe a call to Apple Support may help.

Comment: @RuchaParab are you able to solve this issue??

Comment: any new news here i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

It is not something we can do anything about only apple support can help. The problem got resolved within 24hrs after ticket was raised.